# Set default values for omitted fields with Haskell Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I'm using Aeson to accept user configuration in JSON format, where some fields may be omitted and the default values would be used. According to [doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.2.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:allowOmittedFields) I should write something like this:

```hs
import           Data.Aeson
import           GHC.Generics

data Person = Person
  { name :: String
  , age  :: Int
  } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance FromJSON Person where
  omittedField = Just $ Person "Unnamed" (-1)
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions { allowOmittedFields = True }

main :: IO ()
main = do print (eitherDecode @Person "{}")
          print (eitherDecode @Person "{\"name\":\"Bob\"}")
          print (eitherDecode @Person "{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":42}")
```

Does not really work:

```
Left "Error in $: parsing Main.Person(Person) failed, key \"name\" not found"
Left "Error in $: parsing Main.Person(Person) failed, key \"age\" not found"
Right (Person {name = "Bob", age = 42})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `omittedField` definition in your `FromJSON` instance applies to fields of type `Person` in a larger data structure, not the fields of `Person` itself.

One solution is to make names and ages into their own types, and define `omittedField` for those types.

```
newtype Name = Name String
  deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON Name where
  omittedField = Just (Name "Unnamed")
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions
```

However, instead of using the arbitrary values `Name "Unnamed"` and `Age (-1)` to signal the absence of a value, you could just as well wrap the fields of `Person` in `Maybe` instead.

```hs
data Person = Person
  { name :: Maybe String
  , age  :: Maybe Int
  } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

If you need a partially-defined `Person` with `Maybe`-wrapped fields in some parts of the code and a fully-defined `Person` with ordinary fields elsewhere, you could define them both.

```
data PersonMaybe = PersonMaybe
  { name :: Maybe String
  , age  :: Maybe Int
  }
```

```
data Person = Person
  { name :: String
  , age  :: Int
  }
```

Then it’s straightforward to convert `PersonMaybe -> Maybe Person` if needed. The “higher-kinded data” (HKD) pattern can help save some repetition, but it’s a bit more advanced and usually not worthwhile unless you have many fields and more than just 2 states.

```
{-# Language TypeFamilies #-}

type family Field f a where
  Field Identity a =   a
  Field f        a = f a

data PersonOf f = PersonOf
  { name :: Field f String
  , age  :: Field f Int
  }

type PersonMaybe = PersonOf Maybe
type Person      = PersonOf Identity
```

Comment: That's a bit disappointing as `PersonMaybe -> Maybe Person` would not be easy to write in the actual scenario where there are 10+ fields. Anyway thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @Futarimiti: No problem. It’s boring but simple with `Applicative`—in fact the original [Higher-Kinded Data](https://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/) article shows a nearly identical example: `validate (MaybePerson name age) = Person <$> name <*> age`. If there are more fields you just add one `(<*>)` each. The article then describes ways to remove this boilerplate too, and there are libraries such as [`hkd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hkd) for that as well.